# Serving gzipped files with gulp?

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gzip

I'm using `gulp-gzip` in my gulp file to compress my CSS and JS files and the compressed files out as `app/assets/css/style.min.css`  and `app/assets/js/app.min.js` respectively before launching the gulp server.

How do I get my gulp server to serve the compressed files? A quick search points me to the [`connect-gzip-static`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-gzip-static) package, but this doesn't work:

```
var gzstatic = require('connect-gzip-static');

// Browser Sync
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    files: ['**.*', 'ui/**.*'],
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
    middleware: gzstatic('app')
  })
})
```

Comment: Github to the rescue: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/451#issuecomment-78521056. EDIT: The linked method sounds like if you do it this way then you don't need to (i.e. shouldn't) gzip them first, if it's acceptable to you to compress them on the fly instead of once at build time.

Comment: So now I notice it looks like you're making the point to gzip them first and not on the fly, in that case [this github conversation](https://github.com/BrowserSync/recipes/issues/4#issuecomment-107456522) is the one you want :)

Comment: @Adam Yes I saw that and tried, doesn't work, but upvoted your comment for relevance anyway.

Comment: But that's not the code in **your** post - the github conversation specifically says you can't add the middleware with connect-gzip-static as a plain configuration option and must do it inside a callback, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @Adam Yes I tried that independently... :/